# Are type definitions for `forwardRef` and `useRef` compatable in React 18.X?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have took [this example](https://timmousk.com/blog/react-call-function-in-child-component/) with `forwardRef` and `useRef` for the base:

```js
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    log() {
      console.log("child function");
    }
  }));

  return <h1>Child</h1>;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => ref.current.log()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But this is the JavaScript (JSX), not TypeScript.
The target is annotate all types coorectly.

Let us begin from the child:

```js
const Child : ForwardRefExoticComponent<Child.Props> = forwardRef<Child.PublicMethods, Child.Props>(
  (
    props: ForwardedRef.Props,
    reference: ForwardedRef<Child.PublicMethods>
  ): ReactElement => {
    // ...
  }
}

namespace Child {

  export type Props = Readonly<{ 
    ref?: ForwardedRef<Child.PublicMethods>
  }>
 
  export type PublicMethods = Readonly<{
    log: () => void;
  }>;

}
```

No TypeScript errors for now.
According the type definitions for `forwardRef`,

```js
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;

interface ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P = {}> {
  (props: P, ref: ForwardedRef<T>): ReactElement | null;
  // ...
}

type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null;
```

Now, the parent.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const ref: React.MutableRefObject<Child.PublicMethods | undefined> =
      useRef<Child.PublicMethods>();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={() => ref.current.log()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error TS2322 will occur at `<Child ref={ref} />`:

> Type MutableRefObject<Readonly<{ log: () => void; }> | undefined> is not assignable to type
> MutableRefObject<Readonly<{ log: () => void; }> | null>

Accoridng the type definitions for `useRef`,

```js
function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;

function useRef<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;

function useRef<T = undefined>(): MutableRefObject<T | undefined>;
```

Are type definitions for `forwardRef` and `useRef` incompatable, or I have annotated something incorrectly?

Please no guideline advances like "you should use interfaces instead of type aliases" or "you don't need annotate each type in TypeScript".

Comment: Can you create an example in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that does not have syntax errors or extraneous TS errors please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The type definition for `forwardRef` looks like this:

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

It can be seen it accepts props with type `PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>` but let's focus on the type definition for the ref attribute: `RefAttributes<T>`. This definition and the definitions it references looks like this:

```
interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}

type RefCallback<T> = { bivarianceHack(instance: T | null): void }["bivarianceHack"];

type Ref<T> = RefCallback<T> | RefObject<T> | null;

interface RefAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
    ref?: Ref<T> | undefined;
}
```

Evaluating the above would yield the resultant type for the ref attribute:

```
interface RefAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
    ref?:
    | (instance: T | null): void
    | { readonly current: T | null; }
    | null
    | undefined;
}
```

Now we understand the acceptable types for the ref attribute/prop in `<Child ref={ref} />`. Next we need to see the type for the ref passed into the prop. For that we need to see what `useRef` returns. Here's the type definition for `useRef`, which is a function with 3 overloads, along with the types they reference:

```
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
    current: T;
}

interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}

function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;

function useRef<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;

function useRef<T = undefined>(): MutableRefObject<T | undefined>;
```

Only 1 will be matched, depending on how `useRef` was called. So let's look at how `useRef` was called to figure it out (the type annotation for `ref` was omitted for brevity):

```
const ref = useRef<Child.PublicMethods>();
```

`useRef` was called with no arguments. The first two overloads expect an argument so they won't be matched. The last overload has no arguments so will be matched. As a result `ref` will be typed as (with `T` being `Child.PublicMethods`):

```
{ current: T | undefined }
```

With the type for the ref prop and the type for the ref passed to that prop, a comparison be made to see if they are suitable for each other:

```
// Expects:
(instance: T | null): void | { readonly current: T | null; } | null | undefined;

// Received:
{ current: T | undefined }
```

There isn't a match hence the type error.

## Solution

It can be seen if a ref object was to be passed into the ref prop, the type of its `current` property needs to be `T | null`. With this information, `useRef` needs to be called with `null` as its initial argument:

```
const ref = useRef<Child.PublicMethods>(null);
```

This will cause the second overload to be matched which returns the ref objected typed in a way that's acceptable for the ref prop.

[**Demo in TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBi0A7ilACbIBmAogB4QzBoDCE4EAdkh1gcaWSQUklbMnQxqAGyQhuvSv3JVsAVwDOSAJLgkUFIwBuSABIoOZGWs1U4AXziUobOACIoqDK4DcAWABQAWic6vDMABbAUmQAXHxQJMoidAxMrOxcPAA8EVFkAHQACs5g6gB8cAC8jkrClDmR0UWqAEZSTACySDDhEGTq2LlNxRClZQAUAXBwk-7T02Al6nFDBSOlmFPzHpR63GhIcYQJAkJUDXnNbZ3dvf1lWwCUceIY0rLyVRU4W9Ma2rp9EZTOZLEhxjs9hwDthxo8vjMfnN5tMpBAAOZw3C-FFwYIcdQQGT5NGY1xoRpkRyqaGMTiuR5+ZEouw4uyPRkBHEeGCqKAcOBZcIARjKqyyAHoRWUmdNWf5OYF-BwUHJ1GB0Eg4KtsUrpkhaJBYHAYABPMBa9bqKqIVBkThSU1ZPDckQAfiOtTOIguw1a7TQXR6fXKWzsDzmWwNRvgZotcEK-puwf6NvE9o4judONJcSxlQqhggwDIsvsMq5-gclfxoQTpE+1Xz3y2tfgOxt-3OqyuAaDd3K4w4qikUkVWx5fIFsxRWTIwEMEdxgp1O0qOB2DglS9xWRaqhgME4cE4zADAGt1824Dt8mg+R4eG6SRi4eGz0xz5L94fODvppK86Lk8TJ2N4QA)

## Further reading

- [Type definition for `forwardRef`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d0c02d9f65508d834b39827ba3b9e368607cbc1f/types/react/index.d.ts#L823)
- [Type definitions for `useRef`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d0c02d9f65508d834b39827ba3b9e368607cbc1f/types/react/index.d.ts#L1040-L1078)